# NGINX+MONO FASTCGI+CENTOS - How to avoid idle timeout

Tags: nginx, mono, fastcgi

In IIS there exists the idleTimeout option set at 20 minutes by default. Setting it to 0 allow the application to be always up (never idle) and together with the recycling options, I can decide when the Application must be recycled.

Are there the same configuration options, or something like, in NGINX+MONO FASTCGI? Cannot figure it out.

Thank you
LM

**EDIT:**
It seems that he problem is not FASTCGI. I created a linux service systemd, to startup fastcgi-mono-server4 at boot. It works, but after some minutes (~5) the running application fastcgi-mono-server4.exe starts again with a new PID. 
I want to keep the fastcgi-mono-server4.exe always on with the same PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The problem does not exists. FASTCGI is always up, it was a background thread that crashed the whole application and set the systemd service in a failed state.